# AWS Lambda throws Internal server error due to lambda permission issue, though permission is added through boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I am creating new API resource and methods to an existing API gateway and lambda (They are created by Cloud Formation).
Through boto3 i am trying add new resource and methods. also lambda permissions.
I am able to create all, i could confirm lambda permissions are added in the lambda console.
However when in try invoke the API i get Internal Server Error.

Code below

```
client = boto3.client('apigateway', region_name=region)
client.create_resource(restApiId='api_id',parentId='resource_id', pathPart='resource')

client.put_method(restApiId='api_id',resourceId='resource_id', httpMethod='GET', authorizationType='NONE')

uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:{0}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/{1}/invocations".format(region, lambda_arn)
client.put_integration(restApiId='api_id',resourceId='resource_id', httpMethod='GET',type='AWS',
                       integrationHttpMethod='GET', uri=uri, passthroughBehavior='WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES',
                       requestTemplates={'application/json': json.dumps({"statusCode":200})})

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name=region)
source_arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:{0}:{1}:{2}/*/GET/odm/users8".format(region, account, api_id)
client.add_permission(FunctionName='my_function_name', StatementId="my-statement-id",
                      Action="lambda:InvokeFunction", Principal="apigateway.amazonaws.com",
                      SourceArn=source_arn)

client.create_deployment(restApiId='api_id',stageName='prod')
```

If i manually again integrate lambda with API gateway from API gateway console all works well.
Please let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: lambda proxy integration uses POST. You use GET. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: for lambda you also need `aws_proxy`, not `aws`.

Comment: For lambda integration it can be either of type     type='HTTP'|'AWS'|'MOCK'|'HTTP_PROXY'|'AWS_PROXY', and method can be any HTTP method.

Comment: So which integration you want to use? aws_proxy is the simples and most commonly used for lambda.

Comment: I want to use AWS, because we need to request templates.

Comment: Ok. But you still need POST in the integration as written in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html) "For Lambda integrations, you **must** use the HTTP method of POST for the integration request".

Comment: Thanks a lot, there are two things httpMethod and  integrationHttpMethod,  integrationHttpMethod should be POST and httpMethod is the method we want. This was confused a lot

Comment: No problem. So you get still some errors? Can you post the error messages in the question?